# Firebase CORS policy blocking only for some functions

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, express

I am using FireBase could functions and I get a CORS policy error, but not from all of the methods. For example for my GET and POST (to create a new object) it executes and responds correctly, however, when I try deleting an Object or Editing it, I instantly get a CORS policy error...
The error I am getting:
**Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.**

Server-side

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors);
    // GET method to retrieve a list of CarPlates
    app.get("/getCarPlates", async (req, resp) => {
      await db
        .collection("Car-Plates")
        .orderBy("Name", "desc")
        .get()
        .then((data) => {
          let plates = [];
          data.forEach((plate) => {
            plates.push({
              Id: plate.id,
              Name: plate.data().Name,
              Surname: plate.data().Surname,
              PlateNr: plate.data().PlateNr,
            });
          });
          return resp.json(plates);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    });


    // Getting a CORS Policy error here.
    app.post("/setCarPlate", async (req, resp) => {
      await db
        .collection("Car-Plates")
        .doc(req.body.id)
        .set({
          Name: req.body.name,
          Surname: req.body.surname,
          PlateNr: req.body.platenr,
        })
        .then((success) =>
          resp.json({
            message: `Plate ${success.id} has been modified successfully`,
          })
        )
        .catch((err) => {
          resp.status(400).json(`Something went wrong.`);
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

Client-side (ReactJs)

```
  api
    .post("/setCarPlate", {
      name: "Front-end",
      surname: "to REST",
      platenr: "Edited",
    })
    .then((resp) => console.log(resp))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

I also have tried adding this:

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  );
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});

//app.options("*", cors()); // include before other routes
app.use(cors);
app.options("/setCarPlate", cors());
```

Comment: Have you tried executing your API through Postman? If not then please try and see if it gives the same error or not.

Comment: @SagarDarekar I did. Every method works as intended. Postman doesn't need CORS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. Huge thanks to firebase's support.
**So the issue wasn't even in CORS or firebase permissions.
The issue was: bad request and response handling in front-end and back-end.
Which looked fine at first but actually it wasn't.**

**My incoming request was not formated and handled by the back-end properly which resulted in the following errors in the firebase functions -> logs section:**

API: Unhandled rejection
API: Error: Value for argument "documentPath" is not a valid resource path.

My fix:

**Back-end:**

```
app.post("/setCarPlate", async (req, resp) => {
  const plate = req.body.data.platenr; // data handled properly (the fix)
  // some code ... ///
  await db
    .collection("Car-Plates")
    .doc(req.body.data.id)
    .set({
      Name: req.body.data.name,
      Surname: req.body.data.surname,
      PlateNr: req.body.data.platenr,
    })
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
});
```

**Front-end:**

```
await api.post(
        "endpoint",
        {
          data: { // must wrap everything inside data
            id: this.state.id,
            name: this.state.name,
            surname: this.state.surname,
            platenr: this.state.platenr,
          },
        }
      )
```